# Как "рисовать" в командной строке windows?

Tags: c++

В линуксе консольные приложения часто выводят свой прогресс подобием такого: `[####___] 50%`, при этом надпись "обновляется" на том же месте в терминале, а не спамит в cmd, как делает `count <<"сообщение"<<endl;` в винде. вот на такой "спам" я смотрю сейчас, лучше было бы одной "обновляемой" строкой. [image: вот на такой "спам" я смотрю сейчас, лучше было бы одной "обновляемой" строкой]

Comment: @Abyx ничего не изменилось. я могу что угодно так поставить в начало строкИ, но сами стрОки так и будут "спамить". а я хочу, чтобы новая строка вставала вместо старой, псевдо-gui такое.

Comment: Так вроде уже есть ответы на этот вопрос: [cursor position for stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24903904/how-to-set-console-cursor-position-for-stdout); [SetConsoleCursorPosition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732292/setting-the-cursor-position-in-a-win32-console-application)

Comment: '\r' переводит курсор на начало строки. Естественно, в строках не должно быть '\n' - перевода строк. Поскольку символы предыдущего вывода не стираются, то следующий вывод должен быть не короче предыдущего, например, можно пробелов в конец налепить.

Comment: Кстати, всякие бегущие строки выводят в 'std::cerr,', тогда 1) не будет проблем со сбросом буфера, о котором написали в ответе и 2) можно вывод (если он полезен) 'std::cout' перенаправить в файл, а бегущая строка по-прежнему будет на экране.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запустите вот такой код:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    for(int i = 0;; ++i)
    {
        string s;
        for(int j = 0; j < 50; ++j)
        {
            s.push_back(j < i%50 ? '#' : ' ');
        }
        s.push_back('\r');
        cout << s;
        this_thread::sleep_for(50ms);
    }
}
```

Возможно, если у вас не VC++, потребуется еще сброс буфера `cout`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<Windows.h>
int main () {
HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
SetConsoleCursorPosition(hOut, {10,10}); //Эта функция устанавливает положение курсора, то есть можно перерисовать результат
return 0;
}
```